# Компиляция python pyqt5 в exe

Tags: python, pyqt5, design

Не раз замечал, что большинство популярных приложений написаны на pyqt5, такие DLLки есть у них в папках. С помощью чего компилируют такие программы? Чем вообще советуете компилировать графические приложения на python, если есть много файлов, конфиги, как раз файлы с графическим интерфейсом и т.д, чтобы эти файлы можно было "обновлять", а не перезаписывать все приложение?

[Скриншот папки TeamSpeak 3](https://prnt.sc/hgNAojUNOdMM)

Comment: Прикрепите картинку как картинку. У меня в стране ссылки с этого сайта не открываются.

Comment: А ещё список файлов можно выложить текстом с помощью команды dir.